# How can I censor any text in between quotation marks in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am building a text censor program, and i currently have it set up to censor any text from a keylist of words, e.g red will become XXX. However, i want to change it so that it censors any words in between quotations marks. e.g The dog is "red" = The dog is XXX.

I don't know where to start, but this is my current code.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('formSub');

function censorWords(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var textContent = document.getElementById('input');
    //List of key words to censor
    var redacted = ["red"];
    console.log(textContent.value)
    textContent.value = censored(textContent.value, redacted);
}

function censored(string, filters) {
    console.log('in')
    // "i" ignores case, "g" for global and "|" for OR match
    var regexp = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
    return string.replace(regexp, function (match) {
        //this is where the words are replaced with X
        var censorship = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
            censorship += 'X';
        }
        return censorship
    })
}

div.addEventListener('click', censorWords)
```

```css
html {
    background-color: rgb(42, 44, 53) ;
    
}

body h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 1%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

body p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 6%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

.inputform {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20%;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(56, 59, 70) ;
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    .inputform {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 30%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 20%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document Censor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Text Censor</h1>
    <p>This text censor will remove any key words, and replace them with 'X's. To begin, input text into box
        press 'Censor Text', and your censored text is ready to go!
    </p>
    <form class="inputform" name="redacted" method="post" action="">
        <textarea id="input" name="text"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Censor Text" />
    </form>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some HTML in a snippet demo using the editor so we can see what this does.

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit] your question and add a [mre] using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: added the snippet demo :D

Answer (score 0):

```
const censor = (text) => {
  return text.replace(/".+?"/g, (x) => 'X'.repeat(x.length - 2));
};

console.log(censor('the dog is "red" "and" "some" "censored" words'));
// the dog is XXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX words
```

Comment: Page gave a HTTP error 405 when I tried this :(

Comment: @カメシ if you're getting an http error, the issue is not with your javascript :)

Comment: @ChristianStewart, I realised, I put the js in the wrong place. Stopped giving me a http error, but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

We can try a regex replacement with a callback function:

```js
var input = "The dog is \"red\".";
var output = input.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (x, y) => '"' + y.replace(/./g, "X") + '"');
console.log(output);
```

The strategy above is to match the doubly quoted content and capture it in the first capture group.  The callback function then does a replacement of each character with `X`.

**Edit:** This should run on earlier versions of JavaScript:

```js
var input = "The dog is \"red\".";
var output = input.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, function(x, y) {
    return '"' + y.replace(/./g, "X") + '"';
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Tried this and my page crashed, giving a HTTP error 405. Not sure why

Comment: @カメシ Check my updated answer for a version which should not give you errors.

Comment: This doesnt work as the input is a text area, so there isnt a defined value